# Asymptotic growth of $\log(n^n + n)$

Tags: asymptotics

I would like to know if my understanding of this is correct:

The question asks to show that the Big-Oh of the following function is $O(n\log(n))$

$$
\log(n^n + n)
$$

I think the first step is to play with the expression so:

$$
\log(n^n + n) = \log(n(n^{n-1}+1)) = \log(n) + \log(n^{n-1}+1)
$$
However, I don't know what to do next.
Please help me move forward.
Thanks.

Comment: Since $f \in O(f)$ for all $f$, it's not clear what you mean by "[the] Big-Oh of ...".

Comment: It is a multiple choice question that asks for the most appropriate big-oh, the answer is O(nlogn) and I'm not sure why that is the case.

Comment: If you have candidate answers, try computing the limit of the respective fractions and use the lemma from the reference question I linked.

Comment: There is no such thing as "The big-O of a function". It's like saying "What is the integer smaller than $\pi$?" There are infinitely many.

Comment: Would asking: Show that the expression log(n^n + n) is O(nlogn) be more appropriate?

Comment: @AverageStudent Yes, that would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You could continue with
\begin{align*}
    \log n + \log (n^{n-1}+1)
        &\leq \log n + \log(2n^{n-1})\\
        &= \log n + (n-1)\log 2n\\
        &= \log n + (n-1)\log 2 + (n-1)\log n\\
        &= O(n\log n)\,.
\end{align*}
(Leaving out whatever steps you feel are obvious.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use $\log(a+b) = \log a + \log(1+b/a)$ this;

Write the $\log(n^n+n)$ as $\log(n^n+n) = \log(n^n) + \log(1+n/n^n)$

$ \log(n^n) + \log(1+n/n^n) \in \mathcal{O}(n \log n)$

note $n/n^n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$